# Exporting Specific Range of Cells to PDF - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to save and export a current sheet in Excel as a PDF using vba. The code is working, however the PDF that is being published is the entire sheet (which includes a couple hundred blank rows and columns past where I have text. At this link [1](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/10/09/convert-excel-pdf/), there is a tutorial on how to do this through the "Options" menu in the Save As window. I would like my code to do this for me, and select the range that encompasses only where I have text. This worksheet being exported is going to be used by many to create PDF's, with changes in the size of data in this worksheet. This explains my reasoning for wanting to do this through the code automatically as the file is exported. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The PDF is based on your print range, set your print range before you PDF the sheet

Comment: @Davesexcel The print range will change though. The size of the data will be changing, some times bigger or smaller than the previous.

Comment: Showing your existing code is the fastest way to get help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set print area,
This will set your print area from A1 to the last cell in Column "D"

```
Sub Set_PrintRnag()
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A1:D" & LstRw)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Rng.Address

End Sub
```