# Print from webpage to pdf and save to drive

Tags: excel, vba

I need to print from webpage to pdf. the code works perfectly fine to get data. what I am struggling is to print I have the code to print but I am unable to do in a single code after print it have to save it to a default directory with data in column "C".

[enter link description here](https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/04/save-web-pages-as-pdf-files.html) I have looked at this however I am unable to add to current code. ( not sure how to call the code)

also when I add code to current module it throws error as

> "the code in the project must be updated for use on 64-bit"

any help would greatly appreciated

```
Column A               Column B           Column C                Column D
comments               Country Code       Vatid with country code Vatid
Valid/ Not valid       IT                 IT01802840023            01802840023
```

.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE  As Long = 4

Private m_WebBrowser As SHDocVw.WebBrowser

Public Sub CheckVats2()

  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim RowCount As Long

  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

  For RowCount = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    InitializeWebBrowser
    SubmitVat ws.Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 1).Value, ws.Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 3).Value
    ws.Range("A1").Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = ValidationResult()
  Next RowCount

  Set ws = Nothing
  FinalizeWebBrowser

End Sub

Private Sub FinalizeWebBrowser()

  'ToDo: Close
  Set m_WebBrowser = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub InitializeWebBrowser()

  If m_WebBrowser Is Nothing Then
    Set m_WebBrowser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    m_WebBrowser.Visible = True
  End If

  m_WebBrowser.navigate "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatRequest.html"
  Do While m_WebBrowser.busy
    DoEvents
  Loop

  Do While m_WebBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
  Loop

End Sub

Private Sub SubmitVat(ACountryCode As String, AVatID As String)

  Dim CountryCode As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim VatID As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Sleep 3000

  Set CountryCode = m_WebBrowser.Document.getElementById("countryCombobox")
  CountryCode.Value = ACountryCode
  Set VatID = m_WebBrowser.Document.getElementById("number")
  VatID.Value = AVatID
  m_WebBrowser.Document.getElementsByName("check")(0).Click
  Do While m_WebBrowser.busy
    DoEvents
  Loop

  Do While m_WebBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
  Loop

  Set CountryCode = Nothing
  Set VatID = Nothing

  End Sub

Private Function ValidationResult() As String

  Dim Document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim Table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
  Dim Span As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim FName As String
    Dim FPath As String


  ValidationResult = "UNKNOWN"
  Set Document = m_WebBrowser.Document
  Set Table = Document.getElementById("vatResponseFormTable")
  If Not Table Is Nothing Then
    Set Span = Table.querySelector(".invalidStyle")
    If Not Span Is Nothing Then
      ValidationResult = "INVALID"
    End If

    Set Span = Table.querySelector(".validStyle")
    If Not Span Is Nothing Then
      ValidationResult = "VALID"
    End If
  End If

  Set Span = Nothing
  Set Table = Nothing
  Set Document = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Where is the code to print? Which line is indicated for the 64 bit conversion? You have PtrSafe in the above which is correct for 64 bit and I can't see anything else glaringly obvious that would cause that.

Comment: Why not have the code write out to column C and then export sheet used range as pdf specifying filepath to that folder? In the data sample there are 4 columns btw. So do you only want column C? And if so, is that actual question, how do I export column C's values to pdf?

Comment: If so, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508891/exporting-specific-range-of-cells-to-pdf-vba?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa which should help you set the print area to column C used range and have that saved as pdf; again, specifying the folder required in the filepath.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.the code in the example have to needs to be added to the code in the link( https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/04/save-web-pages-as-pdf-files.html)
one is to print results of web page to column A of spredsheet, which is working fine the other is to print. I need to merge both codes to be able to as soon as it updates result the same page needs to be printed.
I am unable to attach a sample file which would have been easier